# Change Navigation Active Class on Page Scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to change the naviagtion classes while scrolling down through different sections of a page but Im getting errors. Here is my current code :

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

  $(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(document).off("scroll");

      $('a').each(function () {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      })
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var target = this.hash,
          menu = target;
      $target = $(target);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
      }, 500, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
          $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
      });
  });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.menu li a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.menu li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}

  })(jQuery);
```

Im trying to use this in a WordPress theme. Is there any mistakes in the code layout that could be causing the problems ?

Thanks in advance.

Scott.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi, Im getting : Uncaught ReferenceError: $target is not defined

Comment: I think the issue is that $target is being used as a global variable with strict mode enabled.  I've posted my proposed solution. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that you are using `$target` before defining it, with strict mode enabled.  Try initializing `$target` in the declaration list (add it to the list with a comma):

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

  $(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(document).off("scroll");

      $('a').each(function () {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      })
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var target = this.hash,
          menu = target,
          $target = $(target);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
      }, 500, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
          $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
      });
  });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.menu li a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.menu li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}

  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it seems to have fixed the target issue. Im now however getting a different error in regards to the scroll function. Im getting this : jUncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost:8888/chase  Any ideas ? thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Sorry please ignore my last comment, it was because i had rows without ids set. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean to making `sticky nav bar`?if so this is how i do.

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/se4a7bm0/